# Different fonts with different locale?

Tags: android, fonts, locale

How to set different fonts with different locale?
lets assume i am having a string file hi hindi but my phone don't support hindi fonts, how to add fonts from asset as default font though out the application?

Answer (score 0):

To add custom font,Please follow below Steps.

1. Create a folder named fonts in assets folder.
2. put your custom font in fonts folder.(You can also put your custom fonts in assets folder).

3.Add below code in your java file

```
Typeface tfFonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/customfont.ttf");
componentName.setTypeface(tfFonts);
```

Comment: But this will work for only one id(componentName) , I need to use it thoughout the app

Comment: Second line you have to write for all the ids available in your file.

Answer (score 0):

First, copy your customized font file (eg `custom.ttf`) in assets folder.

Then, do like this

1) Add this class `OpenHindiFonts.java`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class OpenHindiFonts {

private static OpenHindiFonts instance;
private static Typeface typeface;

public static OpenHindiFonts getInstance(Context context) {
    synchronized (OpenHindiFonts.class) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new OpenHindiFonts();
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getResources().getAssets(), "custom.ttf");
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

public Typeface getTypeFace() {
    return typeface;
}
}
```

2) Add this class - `NativelyCustomTextView`.

```
package com.packageName;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NativelyCustomTextView extends TextView {

    public NativelyCustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setTypeface(OpenHindiFonts.getInstance(context).getTypeFace());
    }

    public NativelyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setTypeface(OpenHindiFonts.getInstance(context).getTypeFace());
    }

    public NativelyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setTypeface(OpenHindiFonts.getInstance(context).getTypeFace());
    }

}
```

3) In your `layout xml`, need to use this -

```
<com.packageName.NativelyCustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hindi_text"
                    android:textColor="#727272"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

4) And in your `activity code`, ***no need to change anything*** -

```
final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(...);

textV.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hindi_text));
```

Comment: But this will work for only one TextView , I need to use it thoughout the app

Comment: any other method is there? because it is a long process as i have already made the app and didn't assign ids to it...better if  i do typeface..

Comment: I found this one the easiest....as just need to add two classes and replacing TextViews (in layout xmls) with this - com.packageName.NativelyCustomTextView (the package name for customized TextView), nothing else is needed to be done

Comment: You don't even need to assign ids. That is optional @TestIitbbs

Answer (score -1):

@Test limbs:this is what i suggest to you:create all the needed font in the activity by this way :

```
Typeface tfFonts =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/customfont.ttf");
 componentName.setTypeface(tfFonts);
```

hindi,bangli,what ever you want.create a current `Typeface`variable and provide a way to set it dynamically.all what you need than is is to assign all your widget with the font typeface you want.

```
lefttext.setTypeface((MainActivity.getCurrentTypeface()));
```

`lefttext` is the widget you need to set its font.
`getCurrentTypeface` is a method you create in the main activity to get a reference to the current font.this way you can assign all widget that you need